# Why does Angular 4 plunker works on Safari but not on Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, safari, plunker

I created an app in plunker using Angular 4.

[Link to the code](https://plnkr.co/edit/aqEUdjOWBRAqUkg4uo8q?p=preview)

I did it at the first moment using Chrome as my browser, but when running anything was happening. After trying various solutions, I decided to open the same plunker on Safari and then worked without an issue.

Could you please tell me why on Chrome is not working my solution?

```
<html>

<head>
<base href="." />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  window.AngularVersionForThisPlunker = 'latest'
</script>
<title>angular playground</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js@2.4.1/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/angular.io/b3c65a9/public/docs/_examples/_boilerplate/systemjs.config.web.js"></script>

<script src="config.js"></script>
<script>
System.import('app')
  .catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</head>

<body>
<my-app>
loading...
</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is excepted behaviour? It work the same on both browsers

Comment: @Vega On my Chrome is not. I just see loading and nothing more and a lot of error in my console like those:
System is not defined
GET https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=... net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in my Plunker. 
After I open in incognito mode and I saw that was working. I decided to check the Chrome plugins, as was thinking that was the issue.
I discovered that was my AddBlocker plugin which was causing the issue.
Now I resolved just whitelisting in the Adblocker the site.
If anyone will have a similar issue a good thought is to check plugins conflicts or issues.